# What is the song playing in Attack on Titan episode 17 when the female titan kills the 2 guys then goes to Armin?

Tags: music, attack-on-titan

I'm searching for the song when the female titan kills the 2 guys then goes to Armin (It's the episode 17 of *Attack on Titan* season 1). I tried searching on YouTube or in the theme itself of the female titan but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It's a part of *進撃st-hrn-gt-pf20130629巨人* from *Attack on Titan Season 2 OST*.

There is a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/IqfqJPckors) that cut out the part to make it standalone.

> Originally a part of "Shingeki st-hrn-gt-pf20130629 Kyojin" from the Attack on Titan OST, this part of the song was cut out to be standalone.
>
> It plays during the first appearance of the female titan in the series.